# Is it off-topic to ask for a download link of an early release build of jdk?

Tags: discussion

Here is a question that I just asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311935/where-can-i-find-an-early-release-build-of-jdk-8u40-linux

It is voted to be closed as it off-topic.

In the first version I just asked for a link to jdk 8u40, as it contains a bugfix for a compile problem that I ran into.

It turned out that there is no jdk 8u40 yet and the bugfix is part of the latest 8u20 early release  build, but I did not know that. I assumed that if it is mentioned as the solution to the bugfix that such a version must exist.

So is it generally discouraged to ask for help on SO if you cannot find download links of important development tools (like JDK)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, that's one of the main off-topic reasons:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

jdk falls squarely under "tool".

Comment: OK, understood. What about asking "A bug ticket mentions jdk 8e40. I cannot find it. Does it exist?"

Comment: The asker already knows the tool they want. They just want a URL to download it. The URL either works or doesn't. There's nothing subjective or opinionated about potential answers.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen That's basically the same question—arguably worse since the answer is either "yes" or "no".

Comment: Yes, I agree. What a shame. When using unstable language features like C++1y or Java 8, it is a common issue that you find yourself stuck a known bug, see that it is fixed and need to get a build of the tool that contains  the bugfix. Of course, you can compile from source, but that is not the fastest solution if you can just grab an existing build.